# Lambda function gets timed out from SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm having this problem and I think I've tried everything to fix it.

the error I'm having is:

`Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out The functions ends succesfully and this time it took 11 minutes and 14.607 seconds to execute`

this is how I configured the aws client:

```
public void configureLambdaClient() throws Exception{
        try {
            ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
            clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(900000);
            clientConfiguration.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
            clientConfiguration.setMaxErrorRetry(0);
            clientConfiguration.setRequestTimeout(1200000);
            clientConfiguration.setClientExecutionTimeout(1200000);
            log.debug("Get socket timeout: " + clientConfiguration.getSocketTimeout());
            log.debug("Max error retries: " + clientConfiguration.getMaxErrorRetry());

            this.awsLambda = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                    .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration).build();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

This used to be synchronous but I changed it to asynchronous to see if that'd fix the issue, the current code to call the function is the following:

```
public CompletableFuture<String> executeAsyncFunction() throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.configureLambdaClient(); //Resets client configuration
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                log.debug("Creating " + function + " Invoke request.");

                InvokeRequest invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest()
                        .withFunctionName(function).
                        withPayload(jsonPayload).
                        withLogType("Tail").
                        withInvocationType("RequestResponse");
                InvokeResult invokeResult = null;

                log.debug("Invoking " + function);

                invokeResult = this.awsLambda.invoke(invokeRequest);
                return new String(invokeResult.getPayload().array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new CompletionException("Error: Couldn't execute the function, please contact the developers, ", e);
            } finally {
                long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long timeElapsed = finish - start;
                log.debug("TIME OF EXECUTION: " + timeElapsed);
            }
        });
    }
```

to get this answer I do:

```
public String executeFunction() throws Exception {
        CompletableFuture<String> execution = executeAsyncFunction();
        Thread.sleep(FIVE_SECONDS);
        while (true) {
            if (execution.isDone()) {
                log.debug("Function done, retrieving answer");
                return (String) execution.get();
            }
            log.debug("Function isn't done yet, waiting a minute for a response");
            Thread.sleep(MINUTE);
        }
    }
```

(the lambda function timeout in aws is also set to 15 minutes)

All advice is welcome :(

I have tried a lot of things but I'm completely lost now, what can I do? on short functions (less than 10 minutes) this has never happened, but since our machine learning model data increased, the functions are taking a longer time to finished and so this happens.

Comment: It's not the best idea to just sit around waiting for some lengthy process to complete. Ideally you would leverage some kind of event notification or, if that's not viable, use a polling mechanism. That aside, one way to make Lambda functions faster is to increase the amount of RAM configured for the function (because CPU is proportional to RAM), so you can try that if one of your Lambda functions is simply taking too long. If it's essentially waiting on some external process that you have no control over then this won't help, of course.

Comment: Why are you using Java V1? This is not best practice.  At the very least - upgrade to V2 and use software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.LambdaClient.

Comment: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/lambda

Comment: @jarmod the function uses a certain amount of threads so increasing the cpu doesn't speed up the function, could you elaborate on the polling mechanism? I rather not use dynamo to store the results of the functions since that would mean restructuring the whole system... again.

Comment: Your post is a little unclear, but I think you are saying that the code shown is invoking a long-running Lambda function and the execution of that function is exceeding the 15 minutes maximum. Given that we don't know anything about that function and cannot see its code, it's hard to suggest how you might fix this but the obvious suggestions are 1) increase its RAM size (and hence CPU) 2) find a way to split the long-running task into multiple subtasks e.g. using Step Functions 3) move the processing from Lambda to ECS or EC2.